# Как получить данные из базы данных на firebase java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

Я заполнил базу данных на firebase, предназначенную для android-приложения, и все данные имеют такой вид:

1. Уникальный идентификатор

   - Адрес
   - Имя
   - Телефон
   - И т.д.

Я хочу понять, как извлечь эти данные из базы, с учётом того, что в коде самой программы нету сохранённых ключей. Как это можно сделать? Ссылку на скриншот БД прилагаю:
[Организация бд](https://pp.userapi.com/c846020/v846020692/52a88/1HrbVDcR6-Q.jpg)

Все записи представляют сосбой набор полей для класса Museum

```
public class Museum {
    private String mname;
    private String adress;
    private String phone;
    private String URL;
    private String website;
    private String trivia;
    private double v;
    private double v1;
    private String UI;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых я бы организовал правильно массив имен , который начинается с нуля. Это довольно просто делается в FireBase.
Во вторых ничего необычного обычная модель, обычный `RecyclerVIew`

```
 private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference DBR;
MyAdapter adapter;
List <MyBase> listData;
FirebaseDatabase FDB;
```

Далее так:

```
 listData = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new MyAdapter(listData);
    FDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    GetDataFirebase();
```

ну и сам вывод:

```
void GetDataFirebase(){

        DBR = FDB.getReference("my_base");

        DBR.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                MyBase data =  dataSnapshot.getValue(MyBase.class);
                listData.add(data);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
```

Comment: Пока испытываю, но IDE ругается на `GetDataFirebase();`.

Comment: GetDataFirebase(); этот метод вынесен из OnCreate отдельно

Comment: Ну и плюс надо переопределить остальные методы, которые создаются по умолчанию

Comment: Оп, извиняюсь, не туда вставил